# Smooth and seamless seeking on HTML5 video player

Tags: javascript, html

I'm playing with the HTML5 Video API. I have a video player and a custom seekbar. I can seek the video using this custom seek bar, but even though the video comes from local and is fully loaded, the seeking is not smooth.

When I move the seek bar fast, the rendering seems to lag behind and only updates after a small delay.

When I pull back the seek bar, I want to see a smooth rewind of the video instead of it jumping back into the end frame.

P/S: Please don't recommend some premium libraries to do that.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const video = document.getElementById('video');
  const seekbar = document.getElementById('seekbar');
  let isSeeking = false;

  video.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
    if (!isSeeking) {
      requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        seekbar.value = video.currentTime;
      });
    }
  });

  seekbar.addEventListener('input', function() {
    const seekTime = parseFloat(seekbar.value);
    video.currentTime = seekTime;
  });

  seekbar.addEventListener('mousedown', () => isSeeking = true);
  seekbar.addEventListener('mouseup', () => isSeeking = false);
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

input[type="range"] {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<video id="video" controls>
    <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>

<input type="range" id="seekbar" value="0" step="0.01">
```

Comment: I ran your code with a remotely hosted video (https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/wdgrz14b/) and it scans smoothly for me using both your range slider and the video control's original slider. I would assume the issue you're seeing is down to the processing power of the PC and/or resources available to the browser as scanning through a video - especially one being resized on the fly by CSS, isn't a trivial task.

Comment: hey @RoryMcCrossan, thanks for help checking. I just tried again with BigbuckBunny and it's also very smooth. I guess it has something to do with the video I used for testing on my local which is quite heavy.